# VsCode stuck at select a device to use

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, debugging, android-emulator

I reistalled flutter and vscode and downloaded a lower version of flutter now my vscode just got stuck at select a device to use without showing the dropdown when I want to debug my code and i dont know what to do

I tried reinstalling the extensions but nothing, I need help.

Help:about
Version: 1.81.1 (user setup)
Commit: 6c3e3dba23e8fadc360aed75ce363ba185c49794
Date: 2023-08-09T22:22:42.175Z
Electron: 22.3.18
ElectronBuildId: 22689846
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22000

Flutter doctor
PS C:\Users\user\Desktop\JxCodie\User> flutter doctor
Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.

even tho I already added it in the settings.json file and in the system environment. Also It says flutter deamon failed to start

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Might also help to add output for `flutter doctor`